# Is it possible to use NMAP to find OS using a MAC address

Tags: nmap

If I only have a device mac ID (sometimes it is not even connected to a WI-FI network), is it possible to use NMAP to find it's OS?

Answer (score 0):

No. OS detection uses fingerprints based on TCP/IP.

[Source](https://nmap.org/book/man-os-detection.html)